# If a continuous function$f: (X, \mathscr T_X) \to (Y, \mathscr T_Y)$ is injective (Given $Y$ is Hausdorff), show that X is hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

$(X, \mathscr T_X)$ and $(Y, \mathscr T_Y)$ be 2 topological spaces. $Y$ be Hausdorff.

$f$ be a continuous function, $f: X \to Y$. To show that if $f$ is injective $\implies$ $X$ is Hausdorff.

Here's how I tried:
Let $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ be two elements of Y. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff we can find 2 disjoint neighborhoods around $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$. Let it be $U, V$ respectively.

Since $f$ is continuous there exists an open neighborhood around $x_1$ and $x_2$ in X (let it be $E(x_1)$ and $ F(x_2)$) such that $f(E) \subset U$ and $f(F) \subset V$.

After this how to use injectivity property to prove that E is disjoint with F??

Comment: You are almost there. Since the neighbourhoods in the image are disjoint, their counterimages are, too.

Comment: Let $O=E \cap F$. So $f(O) \subset U$ and $f(O) \subset V$. Since U is disjoint with V, $f(O)$ has to be empty. $\implies O$ has to be empty. So $E$ and $F$ are disjoint.Is this right?? but where did I use injectivity property??

Comment: You used it *in the beginning*: if $x_1\ne x_2$ then $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$, therefore the disjoint $U$ and $V$ exist.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, $U_* = f^{-1}(U)$ is open, as is $V_*$ with the corresponding definition. They are disjoint cause the images are. The injectivity you need for $x_1 \neq x_2 \rightarrow f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$

Comment: I am understanding why pre images will be disjoint if the corresponding images are disjoint? Which definition/theorem do we use to say this?

Comment: If $s\in f^{-1}(U)\,\cap\,f^{-1}(V)$, then $f(s)\in U\cap V$.

Comment: @richard if images are disjoint, their preimages are always disjoint by the definition of a function; it doesn't matter if it's injective, surjective, continous, etc. also, preimages preserve inclusions, intersections, unions, differences. so $U \subset V \implies f^{-1}(U) \subset f^{-1}(V)$, $f^{-1}(U \cap V) = f^{-1}(U)\cap f^{-1}(V)$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x \neq y$ be elements of X,by injectivity you get $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Now pick a neighbourhood $U$ of $f(x)$ and $V$ for $f(y)$ such that $U \cap V=\emptyset$; $f^{-1}(U) \cap f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(U \cap V) = \emptyset$ and they are neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Comment: I am still not getting why $f^{-1}(U) \cap f^{-1}(V) = \emptyset $. All we can say, using the definition of continuity, that if U and V are open in Y then their corresponding $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ will be open in X. But how do we infer that if U and V are disjoint then their corresponding pre-images are disjoint as well?
------------------------------------------------------------------
Or to say, can we write this: $f^{-1}(U) \cap f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(U \cap V)$ for a general case (where f is not injective). If yes why??

Comment: @RichardJ Let $g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be a map between sets. Suppose given a family $\{B_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ of subsets of the codomain $Y$. Then $g^{-1}(\cap_{i\in I} B_{i})=\cap_{i\in I} g^{-1}(B_{i})$. You can prove this directly by showing the double inclusions (left to right and right to left). In particular, if the $B_{i}$ are disjoint, also the $g^{-1}(B_{i})$ share the same property.

Comment: A point in $f^{-1}[U] \cap f^{-1}[V]$ must map into $U$ (because it is in $f^{-1}[U]$) and into $V$ (similarly) as well. When $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, no such points can exist....